# How can I "ignore clicks" on the firebug window?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm trying to browse the html generated by jquery TokenInput "drop-down" ([example here](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)) using firebug.

Problem is, the dropdown is supposed to disappear when you click outside it. So every time I click on any of the firebug buttons or controls, it goes away :( (not just display: hidden; the html is utterly destroyed)

Is there a way to tell firebug "don't propagate your onclicks to the general page"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little nasty, and breaks functionality, but to inspect the html you can unbind `blur` event:

```
$('*').unbind('blur')
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit nasty, but hey, it should do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sad, but I have not solved this problem too. But try use `Shift+Ctrl+C` on dropdown div.

UPD:

Only for your example:

1. Open firebug console
2. Type `$("#token-input-tokeninput-demo").val("ff").trigger("keydown");` and run
3. Go to HTML tab and search dropdown above `</body>`
4. ...
5. Profit!